# Ajax Reload same page onclick

Tags: jquery, ajax

This is my situation.I have some 10 links on a page. So when user clicks on those links ajax-same page reload must take place.

To be clear I have something like this.

```
<a href="test.php?name=one">one</a> | <a href="test.php?name=Two">Two</a>
```

If javascript is enabled,

Onclick, ajax load must take place.

If javascript is disabled, Then the above should work.

Basically I am using "name" to limit some values of my search page.

Answer (score 2):

Attach click handlers to your links unobtrusively:

```
$(function() {
    $('a').click(function() {
        // resultContainer is the id of some element that will receive
        // the HTML from the link
        $('#resultContainer').load(this.href);
        return false;
    });
});
```

If javascript is disabled links will perform standard requests reloading the whole page.

Comment: This is somewhat working.. But it is printing links twice. How to avoid that.. Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you do....

There's a `<noscript>` tag that is available for those who do not have Javascript enabled on the browser.

If the page renders the `<noscript>` tag, the `<a>` click should run as normal, else the ajax call.

Usually what people do is to write the same page twice, one containing no javascript and the other with.

e.g

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   //Functions goes here...
</script>
<noscript>
  <!-- redirection -->
</noscript>
```

More on `<noscript>` here: http://xhtml.com/en/xhtml/reference/noscript/

**UPDATE**: Use the following DTD on your page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Strict DTD doesn't support `<noscript>`.

Comment: Thank you.. I will look into it. But below code is some what working.

Comment: PS. Check my post to see what DTD you need to use. Sorry to have not included it earlier.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. I guess this can help me easily. I am thinking of doing something like ajax load onclick and reload if js disabled. Since jquery will not be called if js is disabled "noscript" may not be required right?

Comment: Do like GMail does it. When Javascript is disabled, they redirect to another Synchronous page (i.e. only hyperlinks are used) instead of using Ajax. They follow the principle I gave as solution. Try and debug it (use Firebug for Firefox to see code). :-)